# API chaining like behaviour with import.php

Tags: import

Looking to use import.php function to do a big import.

I'm yet to find some documentation that clearly explains it all. Seen this:

https://civicrm.org/blogs/xavier/api_batch_tools

and this http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Imports

But I'm wondering - the way it works, in terms of using a csv that maps to an entity - is it possible in any way to chain entities in the same way the API works? i.e. create contacts with address and email etc in one CSV?

Thanks

J

Comment: Have you considered other options like the CiviCRM Migrate addition Eileen built for the Drupal Migrate module?

Answer (score 2):

I use CSV API import quite heavily - but if there's a way to do chaining, I'm unaware of it.  I use an ETL tool (Pentaho Kettle) to script migrations, so I handle lookups there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would be able to make it do it, but I do not think it works like that out of the box.